# Update function in Presto

Tags: sql, updates, presto

I've seen in this post from a year ago ([Updating a SQL table in presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57485900/updating-a-sql-table-in-presto/57488304#57488304?newreg=752b5c6f1ce5490b8b18ebb264190a4f)) that Presto does not support update statements.  Has this changed?  Is there an alternative way to achieve an update statement on an existing table with existing records?

update table_a
set attr1 = 1
where id in (10001096322)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly with Presto, but Apache Hudi is often integrated with Presto for these use cases.
https://prestodb.io/blog/2020/08/04/prestodb-and-hudi